# Having fun with Javascript

Tags: javascript

If you were to add **one line of Javacript code to every single page on the internet**, and your goal is to break all possible sites for javascript enabled browsers: **what would it be?**

Comment: Have a read up on Samy Kamkar. That's probably right up your street (myspace worm and xxxss)

Comment: `document.body.textContent = null` ?

Comment: If you didn't have 70.1k rep I believe that this question would be closed in less than 1 minute.

Comment: That would be a good question at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: c'mon! it's Friday night in this part of the globe! gimme a break guys!

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz At times, I'd agree it'd be nice if [that side of SO](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions-top100.html) was still around -- the just for curiosity, humor, and/or sanity. But, apparently enough people along the way said, "*Nope*."

Answer (score 7):

```
$ = undefined;
```

I think that should create enough havoc.

Comment: ***ahem*** `const jQuery = undefined` ***ahem***

Comment: Uhhh! That is much better :) Although you could argue mine would also work on IE :p